# Decomposite a complex value function

Tags: complex-analysis

For functions defined on $\mathbb R^2$ and valued in $\mathbb C$, is there a prerequisite $\mathcal P$, such that for any function $f$ fulfilling $\mathcal P$, $\mathbb R^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y) \in \mathbb C$, there always exist two complex analytic functions $g$ and $h$ : $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that

$$f(x,y) = g(x+iy) + h(x-iy)$$
?

Comment: $g(z)=f(Re(z), Im(z))$ and $h(z)=0$. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR sorry I forgot to mention, not to use $Re$ or $Im$ as this will make it trivial.

Comment: Then you have to clarify the question: What exactly can be used? How can you describe a connection between a function defined on $\Bbb C$ and another function defined on $\Bbb R^2$, without using $Re$ or $Im$?

Comment: @MartinR The idea is to only use *neat* functions other than *wildcard* functions as $Re$ or $Im$. But I'm not good at complex analytic, so not sure how to define it rigorously. I tried and modified the question as far as I can.

Comment: If “neat” means “complex analytic” then the answer is “no.” If “neat” means anything else then it is still unclear what you are asking.

Comment: There is always a prerequisite. "$f$ can be written as a sum of analytic functions in $z$ and $\bar z$ respectively" is a pre-requisite which clearly implies itself. More generally, $f$ has to be a real analytic function. You can recast the expression as "$f(z, \bar z) = g(z) + h(\bar z)$", so it is very similar to requiring for real functions that $\phi(x,y) = \gamma(x) + \eta(y)$. It is only possible for functions with a simple structure.

Comment: @PaulSinclair compare to Fourier analysis, not every function can be decomposed to Fourier series but some can, there's another way to describe such functions.. i'm actually asking if there's another description of functions that can be decomposed into $g(z)+h(\bar z)$.

Comment: Complex analytic functions are also real analytic. Also while $z \mapsto \bar z$ is not complex analytic, it is real analytic. Hence if $g, h$ are complex analytic, then $g(z) + h(\bar z)$ is real analytic. Thus the first requirement for $f$ is that it has to be real analytic. I.e. $f(x,y) = \sum_{m,n} a_{mn}x^ny^m$. The switch to $z,\bar z$ give a similar form $f(z,\bar z) = \sum_{m,n} b_{mn}z^n\bar z^m$. Any such expression is real analytic. But it is only $=g(z) + h(\bar z)$ if $b_{mn} = 0$ when $mn \ne 0$.